Why don’t We Use $i^* T\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ For Fubini-Study Metric?
I am currently reading some articles about Fubini-Study metric, including some computations about covariant derivatives and Riemannian curvatures. I know that the Fubini-Study metric arises from the Hope fibration,
$$
S^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C},
$$
while the projection map $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$ is not a Riemannian submersion, since the Euclidean metric is not preserved along the radial action. However, we have the injection $i:S^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, so we have the pull back bundle $i^* T \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ on $S^{2n+1}$, which is just the direct sum of the tangent bundle $TS^{2n+1}$ and the normal bundle $NS^{2n+1}$. There is a metric on this vector bundle, and the map $d\pi: i^* T \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to T\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$ seems to be the Riemannian submersion, yet the domain is indeed not a bundle with Riemannian metric. I am not sure if this makes sense yet.
There is a various formula for the computation of the covariant derivative and the Riemannian curvature on the projective space involving the Hope fibration, for example
$$
(\nabla_X^{\mathbb{P}^n}Y)^h = \nabla_{X^h}^{S^{2n+1}}Y^h-\frac{1}{2} v[X^h,Y^h],
$$
$$
R^{\mathbb{P}^n}(X,Y,Z,W)\circ\pi = R^{S^{2n+1}}(X^h,Y^h,Z^h,W^h)+g^{S^{2n+1}}(A_{Y^h}Z^h,A_{X^h}W^h)-g^{S^{2n+1}}(A_{X^h}Z^h,A_{Y^h}W^h)-2 g^{S^{2n+1}}(A_{X^h}Y^h,A_{Z^h}W^h).
$$
where $A$ is the integrability tensor.
Do those equations still true when we replace the Hopf fibration with the submersion $d\pi: i^* T \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to T\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$? For example, in this case, $i^* T \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is endowed with the flat metric, so the curvature must vanish. Then do we have
$$
R^{\mathbb{P}^n}(X,Y,Z,W)\circ\pi = g(A_{Y^h}Z^h,A_{X^h}W^h)-g(A_{X^h}Z^h,A_{Y^h}W^h)-2 g(A_{X^h}Y^h,A_{Z^h}W^h),
$$
with the redefined integrability tensor?
